# How can i enter multiple data into documents in FIRESTORE

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently when i enter a new value the old one gets overwritten ,i need to store all the entered values without overwriting. I am a beginner at this. thanks for the help.

```
const docRef = firestore.collection("samples").doc("itemData")
  const outputHeader = document.querySelector("#productList");
  const inputTextField = document.querySelector("#item");
  const saveButton = document.querySelector("#saveButton");

  saveButton.addEventListener("click",function() {
    const textToSave = inputTextField.value;
    docRef.set({
        product: textToSave
    }).then(function(){
        console.log("status saved!");
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("got an error",error);
    })

  })
```

Comment: you are pointing to a specific doc under samples collection, thats why its overwritten. use `.add()` under samples collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your ref to the samples collection

```
const docRef = firestore.collection("samples");
```

Now in the button click code

```
docRef.add({
    product: textToSave,
    cost: costToSave
}).then(function(){
    console.log("status saved!");
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("got an error",error);
})
```

this will create documents under samples collection with a unique key.

Comment: i need to add cost along with the corresponding product too...so i need 2 fields in each document under collection....thanks for the help

Comment: You can add multiple fields using comma. I updated in answer

Comment: Do i need to change the rules in firebase when i do this.....coz i get the error   Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /products/{anything=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Comment: did it work before adding `cost` field?. One thing i noticed, you are saving to `samples` collection then rule should be `match /samples/{anything=**}`